# Regular Expression to Parse URI for client ID

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to figure out how to get a RegEx for parse the following url:

```
http://localhost/asdf/client/16/admin/64/edit
```

What I want to get is the number following client. In this case the 16. I tried client/(.+)/ which works for `http://localhost/hot_seat/client/16/admin`, but once I add the 64/edit into the url it no longer works. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your code / regular expression.

Comment: always in the same location? just explode on the slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this since the client ID is an integer:

```
preg_match('/client\/(?P<id>\d+)\/?/', 'http://localhost/asdf/client/16/admin/64/edit', $array);
echo $array["id"]; // 16
```